# Separate line breaks (new line down) in a text file when reading the contents of the file from a directory of text files

Tags: php

I need to separate line breaks in a group of text files in the output. Currently, we can display all the text files in a folder on a webpage in blocks but the text data is combined in the block of text, I would like to learn how to recognize line breaks and move the displayed content one or two lines down to create an easy to read separator.

I have not tried anything as I am stumped on how to recognise a line break and show that.

````
$directory = "feeds/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('/n', $contents);
     echo '<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#fff">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "<tr><td>$item</td></tr>\n";
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);
?>```


Output at the moment is this
@mpgradio - Mark Rogers - Imagining playing on MPG Radios.. Innovative Music Mix - http://www.mpgradio.ca/radio/imm/ Your music could be included in our rotations, just reach out to us. @lacroix_gen - Gen Lacroix - l’extase de l’oubli playing on MPG Radios.. Reflection Town - http://www.mpgradio.ca/radio/rt/ Where you have the opportunity to listen to unsigned independent artists.

Expected output is would be something like.
@mpgradio - Mark Rogers - Imagining playing on MPG Radios.. Innovative Music Mix - http://www.mpgradio.ca/radio/imm/ Your music could be included in our rotations, just reach out to us.

@lacroix_gen - Gen Lacroix - l’extase de l’oubli playing on MPG Radios.. Reflection Town - http://www.mpgradio.ca/radio/rt/ Where you have the opportunity to listen to unsigned independent artists.
````

Comment: First `/n` is not a linebreak, use `\n`, second see `nl2br()` as newlines don't show in HTML. Also, check `file()` it will read it into an array for you.

Comment: Thank you I will do some research.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to show a file date?

Comment: There is changed and modified https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

`nl2br()` converts line breaks to html formating breaks `<br>` for display in a webpage

Second option is to wrap the text output in the HTML pre-formatted tag "pre"

```
<pre>
Pre-formatted text\r\n
will be displayed\r\n
over multiple lines.
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$directory = "feeds/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
$filename = $directory . $file;
$type = filetype($filename);
if ($type == 'file') {
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$items = explode('\n', $contents);
echo '<table width="100%" border="1" 

cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#fff" id="rcorners">';
foreach ($items as $item) {
**echo"<tr><td id='rcorners'>".nl2br
($item)."</td></tr>\n";**

}
echo '</table>';
}
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```